# Coupon code is not saving at quote table in magento 2

Tags: quote, coupon-codes, magento2.4.5p1, sales-rule

I upgraded my website from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1 .

After that when i applied the cart rule with coupon code, it shows the error that

```
The coupon code "GHSDYFEWFCER" is not valid.
```

When debugged, the vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/CouponPost.php file  throws  the error, and found that when product added to the cart, the coupon code is not saved at quote repository.

Please answer.